# How can I tell which external modules I have to install to PHP to replicate the configuration on another machine?

Tags: php, configuration, puppet, system-administration

I can easily do

```
php -m
```

to see the list of the modules loaded by PHP, but the majority of them are included automatically in the base install.

What I need to see are the packages used and not present on a new system, in order to bring its configuration in line with an existing system.

For example, `date` shows up a module to PHP in the list, but there is no `php-date` package that needs to be installed and configured in order to use the date functions.

Conversely, `mysql` shows up in the list, but that doesn't come by default, so I need to install the `php-mysql` package. Some others, like xml additionally require libxml first. I need the list of the PHP modules that do not come by default (on an arbitrary configured machine).

This is only partially related to the question, but I'm trying to automate the config of PHP  with the [thias/php module at Puppetforge](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/thias/php).

Is there any way to determine this reliably, quickly, and ideally, programmatically?

Comment: I found that I can slowly and manually get to this information by iterating over the list of modules and issuing `yum whatprovides "php-$MODULENAME"` then grepping packages out of the results. There is most likely a better & faster way as this is rather brutal. Basically looking for specific packages listed by `yum whatprovides` other than php-common or [no-package-found].

Comment: Deriving a (minimal) Puppet manifest from any running configuration is a Difficult Problem. I doubt you will be able to implement an elegant script to do that for you. Puppet's canonical way would be to 1. implement a type/provider for the resource (in this case, php modules) 2. use `puppet resource` to get a list of present entities on your system, in form of a suitable manifest. This approach would most likely *not* be adequate to your scenario though (also, overkill).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list created manually by running `yum whatprovides php-$MODULENAME` for each module in our config, and then capturing the package providing the module...

```
# root@dev$ php -m
# 'bz2',         # php-common
# 'calendar',    # php-common
# 'Core',        # php-common
# 'ctype',       # php-common
# 'curl',        # php-common
# 'date',        # php-common
# 'dom',         # php-xml
# 'ereg',        # php-common
# 'exif',        # php-common
# 'fileinfo',    # php-common
# 'filter',      # php-common
# 'ftp',         # php-common
  'gd',          # php-gd needs install
# 'gettext',     # php-common
# 'gmp',         # php-common
# 'hash',        # php-common
# 'iconv',       # php-common
# 'json',        # php-common
# 'libxml',      # php-common
  'memcache',    # php-pecl-memcache needs install
  'mysql',       # php-mysql needs install
# 'mysqli',      # php-mysql
# 'openssl',     # php-common
# 'pcntl',       # php-cli
# 'pcre',        # php-common
  'PDO',         # says php-pdo but in common as of 5.3
# 'pdo_mysql',   # php-mysql
# 'pdo_sqlite',  # php-pdo
# 'Phar',        # php-common
  'pspell',      # php-pspell needs install
# 'readline',    # php-cli
# 'Reflection',  # php-common
# 'session',     # php-common
# 'shmop',       # php-common
# 'SimpleXML',   # php-common
  'snmp',        # php-snmp
# 'sockets',     # php-common
# 'SPL',         # php-common
# 'sqlite3',     # php-pdo
# 'standard',    # php-common
# 'tokenizer',   # php-common
# 'wddx',        # php-xml
  'xml',         # php-xml needs install
# 'xmlreader',   # php-xml
  'xmlrpc',      # php-xmlrpc needs install
# 'xmlwriter',   # php-xml
# 'xsl',         # php-xml
# 'zip',         # php-common
# 'zlib'         # php-common
```

I ended up with this in params.pp

```
$php_modules        = ['gd','mysql','pspell','snmp','xml','xmlrpc']
```

and this in my php.pp profile.

```
package { 'php-pecl-memcached':
    ensure => installed,
}

php::module { $php_modules : }
```

I didn't end up doing it programmatically. Hope the list saves someone in the future some time - it took awhile to get it right!